# Apache2 HTTP authentication: don't ask for credentials, return 401 immediately

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

I have an Apache 2.4 webserver that serves some files that should be visible to the public, and others that should only be visible after authentication, which I have implemented with the `AuthType Basic` directive in a `.htaccess` file.

The restricted files will never be accessed by a human with a browser, but only from software that requests them and includes the authentication credentials in the HTTP header.

If the site is accessed without providing the credentials directly in the header (e.g. with a browser), I want Apache to return a `401 Unauthorized` status immediately and not show the authentication dialog. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this by only sending the 401 Unauthorised response (as @davidgo has already pointed out). However, you can't just send another 4xx status instead either; you need both.

You need HTTP Basic Authentication (ie. a potential "401 Unauthorized" response) when the `Authorization` HTTP request header is sent from your software, but respond with a 403 Forbidden when authentication has not been attempted on the initial request (ie. a default browser request).

On Apache 2.4, you can use Apache expressions to make this conditional...

```
# Check if "Authorization: Basic ..." HTTP request header has been sent 
<If "%{HTTP:Authorization} =~ /^Basic\s./">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Private Area"
    AuthUserFile "/home/user/.htpasswds/secret"
    Require valid-user
</If>
<Else>
    # 403 Forbidden all requests that have not sent an "Authorization" header
    Require all denied
</Else>
```

Providing the software sends the correct credentials in the `Authorization` header then it should be allowed access. If your software should send the *wrong* credentials then the expected 401 Unauthorized response will be returned. Otherwise, any request that does not send  an `Authorization` header will simply get a 403 Forbidden and no password prompt.

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: You're welcome. I've just noticed I missed off the end quote surrounding the first expression - I've updated and corrected this in my answer. (Curious, I did test this - without the end quote - and it seemed to work OK without!?)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. According to https://httpstatuses.com/401 a 401 error must be sent with a WWW-authenticate field, which will likely prompt a dialogue box (maybe you could try an unknown authentication type but my guess is that won't work reliably)

There are a large number of 400 series status codes (https://httpstatuses.com/ ) - why not use a different one? 403 would seem to describe your need perfectly.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. 403 would be fine too, any idea on how to do that?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. The specifics will vary from language to language, but you want the webserver to respond with a first header/status ) line like HTTP/1.x 403 Forbidden. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258634/php-how-to-send-http-response-code#12018482 to do this in php.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29878529/how-to-return-a-403-on-php-file-extension-requests-on-apache